# What is causing my screen to not turn off after the established time?

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-tab, 3.2-honeycomb

Screen is set to turn of in 2 minutes. But this does not happen.

#### How to find the cause?

<sup>If relevant I have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab P7500](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p7500_galaxy_tab_10_1_3g-3892.php) running Android 3.2.</sup>

---

### UPDATE

To clarify questions from the comments:

1. Device is not connected
2. I have numerous apps installed, so I can't check who is holding the screen by uninstalling it one by one. I want to find the possible malware by some tool or programmatically.

Comment: Have you checked the apps installed if any of them keeps it alive?

Comment: Is the tablet plugged in and you have "Keep screen on" enabled under development settings?

Comment: Might help to post the listing of apps and services you have currently installed - one of us might spot it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wakelock Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) to find out what app is causing the behaviour. Remember to read the correct procedure from the app's info:

> How to use:
>
> 1 Install the app
>
> 2 Charge your phone above 90% and unplug cable (or just reboot the phone)
>
> 3 Give it a time (1-2 hours) to accumulate some wakelock usage statistics
>
> 4 Run “Wakelock Detector”, it will display wakelock statistics for you!
>
> 5 Check the apps on the top, if they show very long wakelock usage time then you found the cause of your battery drain!
>
> *Note: Wakelock Statistics are gathered since Step#3

Comment: Wakelock Detector requires root, unlikely to help most users avoiding root to keep a secure phone.

Answer (score 0):

Prolly went to battery saver cause you had low battery and changed it automatically, youneed to change the amount of time back to what u want every time battery saver comes on, or dxit the settings in saver

Comment: Who or what is Prolly? And where from do you get the idea of "low battery"? If the battery saver would be the cause, wouldn't the screen rather turn of earlier than never? This somehow makes no sense.

Comment: Prolly *probably* means Polly want a cracker?